# os module can't find time files were created, because "system can't find file specified"

Tags: arcpy, spatial-database, metadata

I have ~200 layers in a Map Document, and I am trying to find the dates that these layers were created on (so I can export to database later). Some of these layers are housed in groups and sub-groups and also in gdbs, and I think this is creating a problem when I try to extract the metadata.

```
# import the modules. 
import arcpy
import os
import time

# specify path of map document where layers are located. 
path = 'Location/1_STATEWIDE/'
er = path + "Tool 10_2.mxd"

# list layers using mapping module. I used this for earlier versions of the code where I had to extract layer longnames and datasources. 

mxd1 = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(er)
layers1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd1)

# loop asks that for every layer in the Map Document, if the layer has a datasource, the os module will proceed to get creation time of the layer. 
The datasource condition exists so that group layers and sub-group layers will not give any results or errors; I just need times for the layers. 

for lyr in layers1:
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        sources = lyr.dataSource
        # need path to call time, so print list of paths before time commands.
        print os.path.getctime(sources)
```

This code gives the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified:     u'\\\\Location\\Terrapins_horseshoecrabs\\2002terrapindata\\terrapin_survey2002.gdb\\beach_survey_2002'
```

So this must be because I am trying to find the creation time for the files in a geodatabase. How can I correct this code to avoid this error?

Comment: The OS is not aware of the concept of feature classes, tables, etc. that live inside a FGDB. All it sees is a folder with a collection of files inside. If you inspect it in Windows Explorer, you won't find a file called `beach_survey_2002`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because a geodatabase is an Esri object and not a filesystem object. You can't get a creation date of a feature class (even in ArcObjects) but you can get the date of the database that it resides in. The first thing you need to look at is `lyr.isBroken`, unreferenced layers are broken and trying to get the path from them will cause issues, then check `lyr.isFeatureLayer` before grabbing the `lyr.dataSource` then use a describe statement to discern the dataset types.

```
>>> d = arcpy.Describe (r'D:\Testing\LineLayer.shp')
>>> print d.dataType
ShapeFile
>>> d = arcpy.Describe(r'D:\Testing\x.mdb\Data\fred')
>>> print d.dataType
FeatureClass
>>>
```

This will allow you discern between shapefiles and feature classes and decide what to do from there.

Read more about [Layer object](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm).

Read more about [Describe](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/describe-object-properties.htm).